# Human body control?

Tags: human-biology

What can we consciously control in our bodies besides our muscles and brain (thought, memory, etc.)? Is the notion **Bio Feedback** related to this matter?

**EDIT:** I mean I can move my muscles at will but I can't order my liver to "work" since it's not managed consciously by the human mind. I heard about having some sort of control over temperature, heartbeat, sweating, etc. using techniques like breathing in martial arts or what they teach at the military to fool the lie detector. So my question is : *What CAN we control?*

Comment: Can you expand your question? At the moment I am not really sure in which direction you are thinking.

Comment: Is it still unclear?

Comment: Please define more clearly exactly what you mean with "conscious control". You can e.g. increase your pulse by hyperventilating, but this is quite different from deciding to raise your left arm. Do you consider both to be examples of body functions we can consciously control?